# Method requires a @DataProvider, even when @DataProvider for @Test method is provided

Tags: java, inheritance, automation, testng, dataprovider

After adding multiple **`@DataProviders`** for package `dataobject` class `UserData` , then renaming class to `Data`, using newly added **`@DataProviders`** called `invalid-email` for testing multiple invalid inputs, results in error : `Method public void Tasks.accountRegistration_5() requires a @DataProvider named : invalid-email`. **What could cause the error?**
It's allowed to use multiple `@DataProviders` in same class.

Here is code:

**Tasks:**

*Take a look at Test scenario 5!*

```
import installations.AppDeletion;
import utils.ColorFormatter;
import utils.tempUser;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.annotations.*;
import screens.*;
import utils.TestProperties;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import dataobjects.Password;
import dataobjects.User;

import static dataobjects.Email.getEmail;
import static dataobjects.Email.getErrorMessage;


public class Tasks {

    private void printTestResult(int testCaseNumber) {
        ColorFormatter.colorize("Test " + testCaseNumber + " Passed!",ColorFormatter.boldGreenColor);
    }

    private AppDeletion appDeletion = new AppDeletion();
    private APKInstallation apkInstallation = new APKInstallation();
    private AndroidDriver driver;

    public WelcomeScreen welcomeScreen;
    public SignUpScreen signUpScreen;

    public ConfirmRegistration confirmRegistration;

    public AddToCart addToCart;

    public LogOutAfterSignUp logOutAfterSignUp;

    public InvalidCredentialsScreen invalidCredentialsScreen;

    public NotificationScreen notificationScreen;
    public int testCaseNumber;

    public String tempEmail= tempUser.unTempEmail; //For creating manual account

    public String tempPassword=tempUser.unTempPassword;//For creating manual account



    @BeforeMethod(description="Starts each session",groups=("StartUp"),alwaysRun = true)
    public void setUp() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // Close System.err to prevent any error messages from being printed to the console
        System.err.close();

        // Set System.err to the default output stream to allow any error messages to be printed to the console again
        System.setErr(System.out);


        // Installs application
        apkInstallation.installAPK();

        // Set the desired capabilities for the test
        DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = TestProperties.setDesiredCapabilities();
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("appium:udid", "emulator-5554");

        // Set the remote URL for Appium
        URL remoteUrl = new URL(TestProperties.getProperty("appiumURL"));

        // Create a new AndroidDriver instance with the desired capabilities and remote URL
        driver = new AndroidDriver(remoteUrl, desiredCapabilities);

        // Set the implicit wait timeout to 15 seconds
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        // Initialize the page objects for the different screens of the app
        welcomeScreen = new WelcomeScreen(driver);
        signUpScreen = new SignUpScreen(driver);
        confirmRegistration = new ConfirmRegistration(driver);
        addToCart = new AddToCart(driver);
        logOutAfterSignUp = new LogOutAfterSignUp(driver);
        invalidCredentialsScreen = new InvalidCredentialsScreen(driver);
        notificationScreen = new NotificationScreen(driver);

        // Reset the app to the initial state before each test
        driver.resetApp();

    }



    @Test(description = "User installs app from the APK file", groups = {"App Download","TC1"}, enabled = true)// Done
    public void appDownload_1(){
        testCaseNumber = 1;
        apkInstallation.testAppDownload(testCaseNumber);

        printTestResult(testCaseNumber);


    }


    @Test(description = "App works correctly after installation", groups = {"App Download","TC2"}, enabled = true)// Done
    public void appDownload_2(){
        testCaseNumber = 2;

        notificationScreen.validatedNotificationButton(testCaseNumber);
        notificationScreen.clickNotificationButton(testCaseNumber);
        //Clicks on button after verification is successful (true)

        //Verify application functioning by clicking button after launch
        printTestResult(testCaseNumber);
    }

    @Test(description = "App can be uninstalled from the device", groups = {"App Uninstallation","TC3"}, enabled = true) //Done
    public void appUninstallation_3() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        testCaseNumber = 3;

        appDeletion.isPackageInstalled(testCaseNumber);
        appDeletion.uninstallation(testCaseNumber); // Return results of app deletion


        printTestResult(testCaseNumber);
    }
    @Test(description = "User navigates to Registration page", groups = {"Account Registration", "TC4"}, enabled = true)
    public void accountRegistration_4(){
        testCaseNumber = 4;

        notificationScreen.validatedNotificationButton(testCaseNumber);
        notificationScreen.clickNotificationButton(testCaseNumber);


        welcomeScreen.clickSignUp(testCaseNumber);

        //Confirm user is navigated to Sign Up page
        signUpScreen.verifySignUpScreen(testCaseNumber);


        printTestResult(testCaseNumber);
    }

    @Test(description = "User is not able to register Account with invalid Email", groups ={"Account Registration", "TC5"},dataProvider = "invalid-email",enabled = true)
    public void accountRegistration_5(){
        testCaseNumber = 5;

        notificationScreen.validatedNotificationButton(testCaseNumber);
        notificationScreen.clickNotificationButton(testCaseNumber);

        welcomeScreen.clickSignUp(testCaseNumber);

        signUpScreen.AcceptTerms(testCaseNumber);

        signUpScreen.fillInvalidEmail(getEmail(), getErrorMessage(), testCaseNumber);
        signUpScreen.clickCreateAccount(testCaseNumber);


    }

    @AfterMethod(description="Runs after each test",groups=("CleanUp"),alwaysRun = true)
    public void lastCleanUp() {
        driver.quit();}
}
```

**FillInvalidEmail:**

```
            try {

                Email.sendKeys(email);
                ColorFormatter.colorize(errorMessage, ColorFormatter.orangeColor);

            } catch (TestFailureException e) {

                throw new TestFailureException(testCaseNumber);
            }
            ColorFormatter.colorize("\nPassed!", ColorFormatter.greenColor);
        }
```

*Email is MobileElement*

**Data:**

```
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;

/**
 * A class that provides test data for Registration tests.
 */
public class Data {


    @DataProvider(name = "login-credentials")
    public static Object[][] createUserData() {
        return new Object[][]{
                {new User("tiweti1200@otanhome.com", "Tiweti1200!", "Unregistered User")},
                {new User("wqji321@gqwasd.com", "Warase3459!", "Unverified User")},
                {new User("xoheto3034@ngopy.com", "qwekwei1932!", "Incorrect Password")}
        };
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "invalid-password")
    public static Object[][] createInvalidPassword() {
        return new Object[][]{
                {new Password("abcd")},//Less than 8 characters, no upper case letters, no digits, no special characters
                {new Password("QWERT")},//Less than 8 characters, no lower case letters, no digits, no special characters
                {new Password("qwertyui")},//No upper case letters, no digits, no special characters
                {new Password("ASDFGHJK")},//No lower case letters, no digits, no special characters
                {new Password("qwerty123")},///No upper case letters,no special characters
                {new Password("ZXCVBX986")},//No lower case letters,no special characters
                {new Password("QWERasdfg")},//No digits, no special characters
                {new Password("FDWkwe!?")},//No digits
                {new Password("qwekwei1932")},//No special characters
                {new Password("QWsd12!")},//Less than 8 characters
                {new Password("qwekwei1932!")},//No upper case
                {new Password("ZXCAS1932!")},//No lower case
                {new Password("!@£$%^&*")},//No upper,lower case letters, no digits
                {new Password("123456789")},//No upper,lower case letters, no special characters
                {new Password("@£%^1932!")},//No upper,lower case letters
                {new Password("")},//No letters, no numbers, no characters
                {new Password("A1!aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" +
                        "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" +
                        "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" +
                        "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" +
                        "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" +
                        "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa")}
        };//More than 256 characters
    }


    @DataProvider(name = "invalid-email")
    public static Object[][] createInvalidEmail() {

        return new Object[][]{
                {new Email("fitop40249asuflex.com", "Email with missing @:")},
                {new Email("fitop40249@.com", "Email with missing domain @:")},
                {new Email("invalidemail@com", "Email with missing dot:")},
                {new Email("invalidemail@.", "Email with missing com:")},
                {new Email("", "Email field empty:")},
                {new Email("@asuflex.com", "Email is missing local part")},
                {new Email("fitop40249@uflex.com", "Email has incorrect domain")},
                {new Email("fitop40249@uflex,com", "Email has comma instead of dot")},
                {new Email("invalidemail@.comqwe", "Email has extra characters after com")},
                {new Email("invali demail@.com", "Email contains 'Space' character")}
        };


    }
}
```

**Email:**

```
public class Email {
    private static String email;

    private static String errorMessage;

    public Email(String email, String errorMessage) {
        this.email = email;
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }
    public static String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public static String getErrorMessage() {return errorMessage;}

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Email{" +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", errorMessage='" + errorMessage + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

}
```

Commenting out that specific Test or using another `@DataProvider` doesn't resolve issue, not using `@DataProvider` results in test running succesfully , ofcourse without `fillInvalidEmail`

Tried to use multiple `@DataProviders` for multiple Testing scenarios inside `Tasks`, results in `TestNGException` which tells that used `@DataProvider` is required, even when it is mentioned in `@Test` notation.

**Update:**

Changing name of `@DataProvider` did not fix error;

Removing space in `increateInvalidEmail()` did not fix error

**Solution:**

When using `Inherited @DataProvider` from different class , you must provide `dataProviderClass` in **@Test** annotation for `Inherited @DataProvider` to work.

Another minor issue:
`Tasks.accountRegistration_5()] has no parameters defined but was found to be using a data provider (either explicitly specified or inherited from class level annotation).`

To fix this change 2 things:

1.

```
import static dataobjects.Email.getEmail;
import static dataobjects.Email.getErrorMessage;
```

replace with :

`import dataobjects.Email;`

2. Pass it as parameter to accountRegistration_5() method

`Like this:`

```
@Test(description = "User is not able to register Account with invalid Email",
            groups ={"Account Registration", "TC5"},
            dataProviderClass = dataobjects.Data.class,
            dataProvider = "invalid-email"
            ,enabled = true)
public void accountRegistration_5(Email email){
             

signUpScreen.fillInvalidEmail(Email.getEmail(), Email.getErrorMessage(), testCaseNumber);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have data provider defined in different class. So you should also specify that class as a parameter to `@Test` annotation along with data provider name. Like this:

```java
@Test(description = "User is not able to register Account with invalid Email", 
        groups ={"Account Registration", "TC5"},
        dataProvider = "invalid-email",
        dataProviderClass = your.package.Data.class, // <-- put your Data class here 
        enabled = true)
```

Comment: You are right! DataProvider In TestNG can be used in different classes, as it was in my case. So when using Inherited DataProvider In TestNG I had to use ```dataProviderClass```!